# Permanent redirect for www to non-www site using NextJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, digital-ocean

I've built a website with Nextjs (using version `12.1.4`). For SEO purposes I would like to make a permanent redirect for my `www` version of the site to my `non-www`. Normally this could easily be done with nginx or an `.htaccess` file with apache. However, static websites hosted on Digitalocean are not running apache or nginx so an .htaccess file won’t do. I've read that this should be possible using [Nextjs redirects](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects).

I've tried the following 3 redirects:

```
  redirects: async () => [
    {
      source: '/:path*',
      has: [
        {
          type: 'host',
          value: 'www',
        },
      ],
      destination: '/:path*',
      permanent: true,
    },
  ],

---------------------------------------------------

  redirects: async () => [
    {
      source: '/:path*/',
      has: [
        {
          type: 'host',
          value: 'www',
        },
      ],
      destination: '/:path*/',
      permanent: true,
    },
  ],

------------------------------------------------------

  redirects: async () => [
    {
      source: '/:path*',
      has: [{ type: 'host', value: 'https://www.cvtips.nl/' }],
      destination: 'https://cvtips.nl/:path*',
      permanent: true,
    },
  ],
```

All of them don't seem to redirect to the non-www version. I don't know if it is relevant, but I do use `trailingSlash: true` in the config.

Next thing I tried is adding a middleware file. I both tried adding it at the root and calling it `middleware.js` and inside the pages folder calling it `_middleware.js`.

This is the code I use for the redirect:

```
--> https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/33554
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const host = req.headers.get('host');
  const wwwRegex = /^www\./;
  // This redirect will only take effect on a production website (on a non-localhost domain)
  if (wwwRegex.test(host) && !req.headers.get('host').includes('localhost')) {
    const newHost = host.replace(wwwRegex, '');
    return NextResponse.redirect(`https://${newHost}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, 301);
  }
  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

Also does not work at all... Doesn't do anything I believe.

How can I redirect a Nextjs website from `www` to `non-www`?

Comment: Easier to just to it with a .htaccess file no?

Comment: @Matt Hi Matt, that was the first thing I looked at. However, static websites hosted on Digitalocean are not running apache or nginx so an .htaccess file won’t do. I've updated the question with this information.

Comment: You can do it via the app panel in digital ocean then

Comment: @Matt No I can't. I've already contacted Digitalocean support for this. They do not have this feature.

Comment: Really. I cant remember the dashboard that well but there should be a routes tab which you used to be able to set up routes in that

Comment: It has GOT to be running on a web server. Which one is it? And what do you mean by "does not work at all"? Did you try console.log for the variables?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `https://`, if you test it on a local machine you should restart the server. Starting with Next.js 12, middleware runs at the edge, which means it's executed as close to the user as possible on the Vercel Edge Network or other supported platforms. DigitalOcean's standard approach to hosting Next.js applications involves using a [DigitalOcean Droplet configured](https://docs.digitalocean.com/developer-center/deploying-a-next.js-application-on-a-digitalocean-droplet) with Nginx as a reverse proxy.​​​​​​

```js
redirects: async () => [
  {
    source: '/:path*',
    has: [
      {
        type: 'host',
        value: 'www.cvtips.nl',
        // remove  https://
      },
    ],
    destination: 'https://cvtips.nl/:path*',
    permanent: true,
  },
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I Hope this code is helpful

In your **next.config.js** file, you can set up a rewrite rule to redirect from www to non-www like this

```
module.exports = {
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/:path*',
        has: [
          {
            type: 'host',
            value: 'www.yourdomain.com',
          },
        ],
        destination: 'https://yourdomain.com/:path*', // Redirect to non-www version
        permanent: true,
      },
    ];
  },
};
```

You can create a file named **middleware.js** in your Next.js project's root directory and paste the below code

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(req, ev) {
  const host = req.headers.get('host');
  const wwwRegex = /^www\./;

  if (wwwRegex.test(host) && !req.headers.get('host').includes('localhost')) {
    const newHost = host.replace(wwwRegex, '');
    return NextResponse.redirect(`https://${newHost}${req.nextUrl.pathname}`, 301);
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}
```

make sure to include this middleware in your **next.config.js** like this

```
module.exports = {
  async middleware() {
    return require('./middleware');
  },
};
```

Remember to restart the Next.js server after adding the middleware file and modifying the **next.config.js**.